# Need to download 50,000 images or more

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently, i am downloading multiple images with below code. In My app need to download 50,000 images or more.
When memory consumption reaches to 600 MB application crash due to memory pressure.

When I download 10K images its working fine.But when I want to download 20K images from a server then after downloading 9-10K images application crash due to memory pressure.

I also try to Instrument to find memory leak but there is no memory leak.

In Debug Session (When download 20K images) : 
**Memory Consumption** : 500-600 MB and After that its crash.
**CPU Usage** : 130 -160%

Can you please help me what I did wrong in my code?

```
- (void)Downloadimages:(NSMutableArray *)aMutArray
{
    //newchange
    SDImageCache *imageCache = [SDImageCache sharedImageCache];
    [imageCache clearMemory];
    [imageCache clearDisk];

    // NSLog(@"DocumentsDirectory Path : %@", DocumentsDirectory);
    NSMutableURLRequest *urlRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

    static AFURLSessionManager *sessionManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        sessionManager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
    });

    __block int iCounter = 0;

    for (NSInteger aIndex = 0; aIndex < aMutArray.count; aIndex++)
    {

        NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aMutArray[aIndex]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:(aMutArray.count * 120)];

        //   urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:aMutArray[aIndex]] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:100];
        //NSLog(@"%@",urlRequest);
        // [urlRequest setTimeoutInterval:(aMutArray.count * 120)];


        NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [sessionManager downloadTaskWithRequest:req progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response)
            {
                return [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[DocumentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:urlRequest.URL.lastPathComponent]];
            }

            completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error)
            {
                iCounter ++;

                if (!error){
                    //  NSLog(@"(%ld) SUCCESS : %@",(long)aIndex, aMutArray[aIndex]);
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"(%ld) ERROR : %@",(long)aIndex, aMutArray[aIndex]);
                  //  [CommonMethod DeleteImageWithName:filePath.lastPathComponent];
                }

                [labelSyncProducts setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Syncing Images %d of %lu", iCounter, (unsigned long)aMutArray.count]];
                [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantPast]];

                    if (aMutArray.count == iCounter)
                    {
                        [self controlsEnableDisable:true];
                    }
        }];

        [downloadTask resume];
    }
}
```

Comment: download 50K images in app? It is insane man. I would really suggest you to find an alternative. 50k images will ruined your app performance

Comment: Why don't you use Paging like Facebook or instagram whatever images are useful just download that..

Comment: @Dev_Tandel Its project requirement

Comment: If you are going to make a code which will download 50k images, Then you are making sure that your app would not normally perform. Rather the doing this, use **Lazy loading** concept. Download only those images what u need at a time.

Comment: My application requirement its different. In response, whatever response i got means (10K images or 20K images or 50K images ) from json I download that image in my devices and use further for offline purpose.

Comment: @DaxeshNagar Your application requirements are flawed. Change the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you not to download this many images in the app, this will increase your app size on device.

Even though you want to do, then this is the solution.

**As you know, every image you download will store temporary in RAM. As number of images increases RAM occupation increases. At one point RAM will full and app terminates.**

**For solving this, Download some images and save them. After saving, remove this images from RAM and start downloading some more images and save them.**

**Continue this process until you are done with all images.**

This may solve your problem.

Comment: but eventually, even this approach will run out of space on the device, unless the images are tiny

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the amount of images to download, Download task does not use memory to hold images, but rather just save the image directly to sandbox which is fine. But the problem here lies in the concurrent NSURLSession that you run. Imagine you have 50,000 NSURLSession tasks in memory. That is what make the app crash.

```
for (NSInteger aIndex = 0; aIndex < 50000; aIndex++)
{

  // NSURLSESSION BLOCK

}
```

What you need to do is a queued downloads. You need to handle this by yourself. For example, at one time, download 10 images first, then after 10 is done, then download next 10 and so on. But... it is crazy really. Who would want to wait for 50,000 images to be downloaded???